Is there a sketch in French similar to Abbott and Costello's who's on first
This is the sketch I am talking about, where they play on the idea of turning questions words such as 'what' and 'who' into proper names:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sYOUFGfK4bU&ab_channel=UniversalPictures
In this film dubbed into French the translation works reasonably well.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jlcwDJaByHQ&ab_channel=CMOVIES

Just for completeness - this one was making rounds in 2000

Cool, I appreciate you taking time to help me out.

Un sketch de Raymond Devos, sur où est Caen... Where is when (Caen - a french city - sounds like quand - when in french) et d'autres jeux de mot avec des villes : Troyes (sounds likes trois, three) Sètes (sounds like sept, seven) etc.
https://vimeo.com/208851589

Yea, that is a funny sketch.  Thanks for sharing it with me.

I'm not sure if there is a full on sketch based around that idea in French, but the closest that comes to mind is a movie scene in "Le diner de cons" (The Dinner Game) where a character's first name that is also a word - Just - leads to all sorts of misunderstandings. Francois Pignon, much like Sebastian Dinwiddle, is the dimwit who serves as comical fuel for the scene.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UYYwaFy05-U
This short sketch by Les Robins des Bois also plays on proper noun vs common noun confusion.

Cool, thanks for the help.
